# How to change camera popup direction from bottom to left side with image_picker library?

Tags: flutter, camera, direction, imagepicker

I'm making flutter app.

When I use image_picker library,

https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

I set image source to camera.

```dart
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

XFile? preImageFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
```

And that camera view popup from bottom to top.

But I want camera view popup from left to right.

[app page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOmPz.jpg)

Is there any way to change popup direction?

thanks for reading..

Comment: Hello, please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks, I would refer to that link :D